# Multiple Select and Where into one Query

Tags: mysql

I am quite new to large queries in MySQL, I have been writing a script that is to be used to display information to our internal sales team of their daily totals, including calls, and sales figures, this is working at the moment but on two separate screens which I want to merge into one.

Currently, I have two MySQL statements -

Call Stats -

```
SELECT  extension,COUNT(*) as CALLS
FROM mp_wp_call_report_pstn
WHERE  `created` >= CURDATE() AND `extension` !=2504 AND `Call_type` = "Incoming" 
GROUP BY extension
```

Sales Stats -

```
SELECT `Your_Name` as agentname,sum(`Sale_Amount`) as totalsales, COUNT(*) as NoSales
FROM mp_wp_sales_tracking
WHERE `created` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()
GROUP BY agentname
```

What id like to do is merge these two statements, but they are from different tables, is there anyway we can merge them?

This has to be done purely in MySQL, as the software we use to display only supports MySQL Queries.

Comment: they seem to report on completely different things as far as I can see. Perhaps you can clarify what the data represents, otherwise it's hard to know if they can be merged and still produce meaningful data. What is the actual output you'd want from this "merged" query? Can't you just put both reports on one screen instead of 2 in the application?

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for your reply, the idea is that they present the following -

Agent Name | Sales | Calls
Agent A | £2500 | 25
Agent B | £6000 | 40

Etc etc

Comment: how do you know which call relates to which agent? I think you need to edit the question to give a clearer indication of the data structure involved, the desired output and some sample input data. Don't forget the only things we know about your system are what you write on this page. So if some particular info is necessary to solve the problem, you need to put it into the question.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, without going to the nth degree to explain the system, its as follows -

Wordpress System, each wordpress user has an additional userfield added called "Agent Extension", which ties back into the phone system, thus why we only need the ID from the extension. The sales are manually logged using input from the agents, we then display that on a screen in the office, a simple table form, showing the calls, sales and a few other screens that are around website sales.

The fields we would need (As in MYSQL fields) are as follows

AgentName | totalsales | calls

Comment: is an "agent" the same as "wordpress user"? Do they have an ID we can use and not just a name? Is that ID present in mp_wp_sales_tracking? What's the wordpress user table called? Is each extension unique to a single user? You haven't tagged with wordpress so you can't assume that anyone looking here has any knowledge of wordpress internals. I certainly don't. Like I said before please **edit the question** with additional details - in the comments it can get lost and is unformatted and harder to comprehend. Show _all_ the relevant data structure, and _examples_ of _input_ and _output_.

Comment: Descriptions like you've given are useful to explain the context, but hard information is what is needed. To write the query I don't actually need to know that the calls are input by hand, or where you put your display screens, I need to know how the table relationships are structured and what the desired output is. Coding is all about knowing the specific, relevant details of the problem.